# считывания чисел из файла с помощью QFile

Tags: c++, qt

Есть файл вот такого типа

```
12286 0 4459 11909 0 4760 12265 0 4206 11942 0 5014 
12216 0 4472 11969 0 4760 12210 0 4198 12001 0 5029 
12205 0 4473 11976 0 4743 12198 0 4208 12010 0 4998 
12183 0 4475 11987 0 4741 12177 0 4226 12019 0 4997 
12177 0 4501 11990 0 4728 12173 0 4235 12024 0 4976 
12165 0 4501 11997 0 4712 12159 0 4242 12029 0 4964 
12158 0 4527 12003 0 4707 12151 0 4259 12034 0 4963 
12151 0 4509 12006 0 4693 12148 0 4244 12039 0 4956 
12145 0 4538 12010 0 4689 12140 0 4270 12043 0 4956 
12143 0 4535 12012 0 4687 12138 0 4276 12043 0 4951 
12135 0 4545 12014 0 4672 12132 0 4280 12048 0 4928 
12134 0 4547 12016 0 4664 12126 0 4279 12048 0 4924 
12128 0 4565 12018 0 4666 12124 0 4302 12054 0 4931 
12126 0 4566 12021 0 4660 12119 0 4313 12054 0 4907 
12123 0 4569 12024 0 4653 12116 0 4309 12056 0 4900 
12120 0 4563 12024 0 4654 12113 0 4325 12059 0 4914 
12118 0 4573 12026 0 4650 12110 0 4315 12061 0 4902 
12113 0 4565 12030 0 4639 12107 0 4317 12062 0 4892 
12111 0 4575 12030 0 4651 12109 0 4336 12065 0 4876
```

Нужно причитать числа с определенной строки с конвертированием в int.

Comment: Читаем построчно или полностью, разбиваем `split()` конвертируем в `int`. Что сложного?

Comment: C++? Зачем тогда `QFile`? Обычный `ifstream`,  доходим до нужной строки, читаем в `int` с помощью оператора `>>`. До нужной строки можно добраться, читая предыдущие строки (если они нужны) или игнорируя `.ignore()`, если нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стоит ещё добавить проверку на число, но я этого не делал.

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>

QFile file("test.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QVector<int> data;

int currentLine = 0;
while(!file.atEnd())
{
    currentLine++;
    QStringList lineData = QString(file.readLine()).split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < lineData.length(); ++i)
    {
        data.push_back(lineData[i].toInt());
    }

    if(currentLine == 2) // доходим, например, до второй строки
        break;
}}
```

Comment: У меня qt4.7.8 и старый c++ . Не знаю что такое for(QString item: QString(file.readLine()).split(" "))

Comment: а так работает?

Comment: за что минус???

Comment: Я не знаю за что минус

Comment: При таком коде условие на 2 выполнится на первой строке, это наверное не совсем правильно.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver мой косяк, поправил

Comment: Зачем результат метода `split` приводить к `QString`? Вам же по пробелам надо побить строку на слова, а потом их привести к числам. `split` возвращает `QStringList`, с ним и надо работать

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Я не привожу `split()` к `QString` Я привожу `QFile::readLine())` к `QString`, т.к. этот метод возвращает данные в `QByteArray`

Comment: а, тьфу, со скобочками обсчитался. все правильно, виноват